# EF.Property called with wrong property name. - Nested Where Clause - EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.0

```
List<Invitation> a = dbContext.invitations
                .Include(i=>i.ArticleReviews)
                .Include("Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers.User")
                .Include(i=>i.User)
                .Where(i=>i.Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers.Where(a=>a.User.Email == User.Identity.Name && a.role == "coAuthor") != null)
                .Where(i=>i.status == "reviewSubmitted").ToList();
```

in above query `Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers` is a list so to load related objects i use hard coded string `Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers.User`.

now the error `EF.Property called with wrong property name.` occur when i use where inside another where to load data for current logged in user

statement which throwing error is

`.Where(i=>i.Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers.Where(a=>a.User.Email == User.Identity.Name && a.role == "coAuthor") != null)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested where use Any Clause like this

`.Where(i=>i.Article.AuthorsAndOpposedReviewers.Any(a=>a.User.Email == User.Identity.Name && a.role == "coAuthor"))`

The ANY operator returns true if any of the subquery values meet the condition

Comment: Can you please explain why would this approach be a better choice?

Comment: @dvlsc All valid LINQ syntax can't be used for Entity Framework, as described above nested where clause is throwing an exception and ANY is the alternate way which is working fine.